# Are AlexNet weights available for Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

The benchmark for AlexNet is part of the Tensorflow repository when I clone it from git. The benchmark implements the layers, but it looks to me that the actual weights for AlexNet are not loaded at any point.

I would like to play around with Tensorflow, but my applications (in caffe) are using a pre-trained AlexNet.

Do you think they will release the weights as well?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of an existing one, but someone wrote a [converter to import Caffe models into tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow), and you can find [pre-trained Alexnet models for Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet) (also see [the BVLC Model-Zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo)).  I can't promise it will work, but you can quite possibly glue those two together to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, there is AlexNet pretrained weights available for Tensorflow, you can download it [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eguerzhoy/tf_alexnet/)**

To load them to your project, you can use the following code (adapted from [here](https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/master/alexnet.py))

```
# Load the weights into memory
weights_dict = np.load('./weight-path/bvlc_alexnet.npy', encoding='bytes').item()

# Loop over all layer names stored in the weights dict
for op_name in weights_dict:

    # Check if layer should be trained from scratch
    if op_name not in self.SKIP_LAYER:

        with tf.variable_scope(op_name, reuse=True):

            # Assign weights/biases to their corresponding tf variable
            for data in weights_dict[op_name]:

                # Biases
                if len(data.shape) == 1:
                    var = tf.get_variable('biases', trainable=False)
                    session.run(var.assign(data))

                # Weights
                else:
                    var = tf.get_variable('weights', trainable=False)
                    session.run(var.assign(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/ has weights as numpy arrays of trained weights on AlexNet. You can use those in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

No,the benchmark file is just implementation and you have to train and evaluate

Answer (score 0):

[This github repository](https://github.com/Eduardo-RP/Pretrained-AlexNet-TensorFlow-with-Weights) from Eduardo Rivas-Posada has AlexNet weights for Tensorflow/Keras. These are not the original AlexNet weights, but recreated on the same model architecture.